# Ubuntu server strange behavior

Tags: server, kernel, php, cron

Please help me ... I'm not a very experimented user ...have some notions but my logic is not working :(

The story is the following

- more then 10 years ago (maybe in 2010) decided to use a PC in our LAN (about 10 PCs) to store the common documents, invoices, datasheets and stuff like this in a centralized location so we choosed to use Linux (Debian Lenny) for our SHAREPOINT, after a few days we've started to use a CRM based on PHP4 and SQL database
- everything worked fine without any intervention only a few small maintenace ... until a month ago
- The main problem was that the PC stops to boot and display the following message
  Kernel panic - not syncing : attempted to kill int ! exit code=0x00007f00
  This error appear even if I'm trying to boot from a bootable USB
  I've tried using BootRepair
  the report uploaded
  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7f8VZCjHW6/
  after the reboot
  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kP7by6mB9d/

I've decided to install UBUNTU ... the latest version
and Apache 2, PHP 7.4, SQL

so the problems:

- crontab is not working neiher the global or the user's or the root's
- the CRM based on PHP/SQL is working about 20xtimes slower
- updated the PHP to 8.0 an the php -v display "PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 07:54:13)"
  but phpinfo() displays "PHP Version 7.4.16"

So please some hints because I'm desperate!

-Computer-
Processor               : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.80GHz
Memory          : 967MB (575MB used)
Machine Type            : Desktop
Operating System                : Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: After 10 years, don't discount potential hardware failure. If not specifically the problem today, soon. Since this seems to be enterprise-critical, make sure you have the data backed up (hard drives die). Work toward complete notes on how to rebuild your system from scratch on a new chassis.

Comment: How can you encounter the latter 3 problems if the pc won't boot?  Or, are those new problems that happened after you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: Does a 10 year old computer even meet the min requirements for Ubuntu 20.04?